# How to use "Authorization code" for securitySchemes for OpenAPI 3.0.0?

Tags: json, yaml, openapi, openapi-generator

In OpenAPI 3.0.0 documentation there is no sample code for **flows** type for **Authorization code**.

The only code here for **implicit** type only.

```
    petstore_auth:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: 'http://petstore.swagger.io/api/oauth/dialog'
          scopes:
            'write:pets': modify pets in your account
            'read:pets': read your pets
```

If anyone knows about the concept please provide me an example in **YAML** or **JSON**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is support for the authorizationCode flow - I'm reading this from the spec http://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.2.html#oauth-flows-object and it looks like you can replace `implicit` with `authorizationCode` like this:

```
flows:
  authorizationCode:
    authorizationUrl: https://example.com/api/oauth/dialog
    tokenUrl: https://example.com/api/oauth/token
    scopes:
      write:pets: modify pets in your account
      read:pets: read your pets
```